# Optimizing Loop for memory

Tags: python, loops, memory, memory-management

```
def getWhiteLightLength(n, m, lights):
    lt_nv = []
    ctd = 0
    for clr, inic, fim in lights:
        for num in range(inic, fim+1):
            lt_nv.append(num)
    c = Counter(lt_nv)
    for ch, vl in c.items():
        if vl == m:
            ctd += 1
    return(ctd)
```

I'm doing this HackerRank solution, it passed on half of the tests, but for the others, I get a memory usage error. I'm new to python so don`t know how to optimize these loops for minor memory usage.

Comment: You could start with not having the list at all and instead just have the counter and add objects to the counter instead.

Comment: How to do that?